# Como retornar os valores de um arraylist em Java

Tags: java

Não estou conseguindo retornar os valores do arraylist. Eu criei uma classe do tipo Aluno com alguns métodos. Em outra classe um crio um arraylist do tipo Aluno e adiciona valores. Porém quando vou mostrar não aparece nada. Usei o `foreach`pra percorrer o array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aluno1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        int opcao, opcao2;

        do{
            System.out.println("0 - Sair\n1 - Adicionar novo aluno\n2 - Mostrar todos os alunos");
            opcao = input.nextInt();


            if(opcao == 1){
                System.out.println("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
                String nome = input.next();
                Aluno aluno = new Aluno(nome);//Instancia um objeto do tipo Aluno
                alunos.add(aluno);//Adiciona no arraylist

                do{
                    System.out.println("0 - Sair\n1 - Adicionar nota");
                    opcao2 = input.nextInt();

                    if(opcao2 == 1){
                        System.out.println("Digite a nota: ");
                        aluno.getNota().add(input.nextDouble());//Adiciona notas enquanto não for digitado zero
                    }

                }while(opcao2 != 0);

            if(opcao == 2){
                for(Aluno item : alunos){//Imprime os valores do arraylist e chamando seus métodos
                    System.out.println("Nome: " + item.getNome());
                    System.out.println("Média: " + item.getMedia());
                    System.out.println("Desvio Padrão: " + item.getDesvioPadrao());
                    System.out.println("Variância: " + item.getVariancia());
                }
            }

            }
        }while(opcao != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cadê a implementação da classe `Aluno`?

Comment: Seu segundo `if` está dentro do primeiro, nunca vai ser executado

Comment: O problema estava no `if`mesmo. Resolvido!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu segundo `if` está dentro do primeiro, do jeito como está ele nunca via listar os itens do seu `ArrayList`

Seu código deveria estar assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aluno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        int opcao, opcao2;

        do {
            System.out.println("0 - Sair\n1 - Adicionar novo aluno\n2 - Mostrar todos os alunos");
            opcao = input.nextInt();


            if (opcao == 1) {
                System.out.println("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
                String nome = input.next();
                Aluno aluno = new Aluno(nome);//Instancia um objeto do tipo Aluno
                alunos.add(aluno);//Adiciona no arraylist

                do {
                    System.out.println("0 - Sair\n1 - Adicionar nota");
                    opcao2 = input.nextInt();

                    if (opcao2 == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Digite a nota: ");
                        aluno.getNota().add(input.nextDouble());//Adiciona notas enquanto não for digitado zero
                    }

                } while (opcao2 != 0);
            }

            if (opcao == 2) {
                for (Aluno item : alunos) {//Imprime os valores do arraylist e chamando seus métodos
                    System.out.println("Nome: " + item.getNome());
                    System.out.println("Média: " + item.getMedia());
                    System.out.println("Desvio Padrão: " + item.getDesvioPadrao());
                    System.out.println("Variância: " + item.getVariancia());
                }
            }
        } while (opcao != 0);
    }
}
```

<sup>Obs.: Alterei mais do que o `if` na classe, adicionei alguns espaços para ficar mais claro e removi o número do nome da classe</sup>